# Is there any row key partition limit in KairosDB

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

KairosDB built in top of cassandra, but the cassandra have row key partition limit, Is that partition limit is applicable to this also?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has the same limitation -- in the [Getting Started](https://kairosdb.github.io/kairosdocs/GettingStarted.html) section you can read what follows:

> Using with Cassandra [...]
>
> The default configuration for Cassandra is to use wide rows. Each row
>   is set to contain 3 weeks of data. The reason behind setting it to 3
>   weeks is if you wrote a metric every millisecond for 3 weeks it would
>   be just over 1 billion columns. Cassandra has a 2 billion column
>   limit.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: But actually my use case is sip,dip,dport. I can get millions of events for every unique combinations of above tags sip,dip,dport. I crossed the row key limit of cassandra 2^64. can I override the limit of row key in cassandra. why am asking is KairosDB is on top of cassandra, so same limitation(2^64) is applicable to KairosDB. when I can achieve this limitation we have no headache to use KairosDB.

Answer (score 1):

we already discussedvia the kairosDB discussion group, but you raise an interesting question here.

I am sure that if you come over 2^64 you will have much more problems than the index capability of Cassandra. Imagine you're only using 1 byte per series, that means 1.84e19 bytes... Only Google or facebook know yet how to store 18 exabytes, which is a cosmic size.